# How to work around GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN

Tags: opengl, input, keyboard, glfw, wayland

On my laptop (MSI GE63VR 7RE) GLFW passes GLFW_KEY_UNKNOWN to the key callback function when pressing the space key (and some other keys).

There is a scancode for almost all keys, but these are supposed to be machine specific and there is no convenient way to map them to the correct key names.

Why does GLFW not recognise my space key as GLFW_KEY_SPACE and what would be the best way to work around this?

Im on arch linux  with wayland and am using the glfw-wayland 3.2.1-1 package

Comment: OS?  GLFW version?  Self-built GLFW or binaries from somewhere?  [mcve]?

Comment: Yep, the problem was wayland. Switched back to Xorg and it works fine.

Comment: @stimulate then please close your question if it is already answered

Comment: I have this problem also with X11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yep, the problem was wayland. Switched back to Xorg and it works fine.